# ¿Como descargar un archivo ubicado en una carpeta del proyecto dentro de un WebMethod?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net

Hola comunidad tengo el siguiente problema espero puedan ayudarme de antemano muchas gracias.

Mi problema radica en la descarga de un archivo específicamente de tipo excel al mandar el nombre del archivo por ajax de jquery y tratar de descargarlo con c# dentro de un webMethod me manda el siguiente mensaje:

```
{"Message":"Subproceso anulado.","StackTrace":"   en System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)\r\n   en System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)\r\n   en System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)\r\n   en System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)\r\n   en System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   en System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   en System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n   en System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.Threading.ThreadAbortException"}
```

Este es mi código:

```js
$("#btn_descargar_archivo").click(function() {             

                    descargar_archivo_excel();

                });


// En esta funcion solo paso el nombre del archivo

 function descargar_archivo_excel() {

        var archivo_descargar = nombre_archivo; // variable que es igualada al nombre del archivo ejemplo. Prueba.xlsx
      
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "Descargas.aspx/Descargar_Archivo",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: '{nombre_archivo:"' + archivo_descargar + '"}',
             
                success: function(data) {
                    alert("Correcto");
                   
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    alert(error.responseText);
                    console.log(error.responseText);
                    jsonValue = jQuery.parseJSON(Error.responseText);
                    alert(error.respose.Text);
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });

        

    }
```

```
 [WebMethod]  // WebMethod para descargar el archivo 
    public static void Descargar_Archivo(string nombre_archivo)
    {                  

        string direccion = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Excel_Carpeta/" + nombre_archivo);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(direccion));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(direccion);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola he logrado solucionar la descarga de archivos usando **httpRequest** abajo muestro el código espero les funciones.

```js
 function descargar_archivo_excel() {

        var nombre_archivo; // variable que es igualada al nombre del archivo ejemplo. Prueba.xlsx
      
       var parametro = '{nombre_archivo:"' + nombre_archivo + '"}';
            var url = "Descargar.aspx/Descargar_Archivo";
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                var a;
                if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {                 
                    a = document.createElement('a');
                    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);
                   
                    a.download = nombre_archivo;
                    a.style.display = 'none';
                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                    a.click();
                    
                }
                
            };
            
            xhr.open("POST", url, true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            xhr.responseType = 'blob';
            xhr.send(parametro);           

        

    }
```

```html
<input id="btn_descargar_archivo" type="button" value="Descargar Archivo" class="btn btn-success btn-block" onclick="return descargar_archivo_excel();"/>
```

Este es el código del lado del servidor.

```
[WebMethod]  // WebMethod para descargar el archivo 
public static void Descargar_Archivo(string nombre_archivo)
{                  

    string direccion = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Excel_Carpeta/" + nombre_archivo);

               System.IO.FileStream fs = null;

                fs = System.IO.File.Open(direccion,System.IO.FileMode.Open);
                byte[] btFile = new byte[fs.Length];
                fs.Read(btFile, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
                fs.Close();

                 HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + nombre_archivo);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(btFile);                   
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

 }
```

Puedes ver esta pregunta de la que me guié.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28165424/download-file-via-jquery-ajax-post